# Serve static file outside of root directory in Koa2

Tags: node.js, koa, koa2

I have a simple NodeJS server that uses Koa2. It serves static files from a `client` folder. However, there is a `config.js` that lives outside of the `client` folder. Right now my `client/index.html` file can't serve that `config.js`.

I'm trying to solve that by adding a router that should serve the `config.js`, like so:

```
let configPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '../', 'config.js');
//app.use(serve(configPath));  // this also doesn't work
router.get('/', (ctx) => serve(configPath));
```

In the `client/index.html` I simply have a `script` include.

```
<script src="config.js"></script>
```

But the browser says that it still can't find `config.js`.

How can I make this work in Koa2?

Comment: I think it should be more like: `router.get('/config.js', (ctx) => serve(configPath));` ... to let the router know that you like to serve the `config.json`

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to work. I made sure the `configPath` is correct by doing a `console.log(configPath);`, to check the actual path.